# How to send a post through javascript in CodeIgniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to send a post form in Codeigniter when click a link:

My html code:

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('clientes/delete/'); ?>" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">Delete</a>
```

I want to do with post method because is more secure to do with csrf protection.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Use a `<form>`.

Comment: Your best bet will be to use a `<form type="submit"><button /></form>` approach, and style the button to look like a plain link.

Comment: `POST` (or any method for that matter) is a property of `<form>` element. An alternative would be AJAX request using post method, triggered instead of default link action.

Answer (score 0):

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/iam_groot/aaeftkhv/

You need to create a global variable in html header for csrf protection:

```
<script>
var csrf_token_name = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>";
var csrf_hash = "<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>";
</script>
```

Edit html link:

```
<a href="http://httpbin.org/post" id="5" class="delete" onclick="return false;">Delete row</a>
```

And add this javascript code:

```
<script>
create_form_post = function(action, fields, target) {
    if(target == undefined) {
        target = '_self';
    }

    fields[csrf_token_name] = csrf_hash;

    id_form = makeid();
    $( '<form method="POST" action="'+action+'" target="'+target+'" id="'+id_form+'" style="display:none !important;"></form>' ).appendTo( "body" );
    $.each(fields, function( k, v ) {
        $( '<input name="'+k+'" value="'+v+'" type="hidden" />' ).appendTo( "form#"+id_form );
    });
    return id_form;
}


function makeid()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 9; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.delete").click(function() {    
        if(confirm("¿Are you sure?")) {
            action = $(this).attr('href');
            delete_id = $(this).attr('id');
            id_delete_form = create_form_post(action, {id: delete_id});
            $("form#" + id_delete_form).submit();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Since you're using jQuery, why not make a ajax request on `.delete` click? Why go through all the fuss of creating a form?

Comment: You can use this code for all the application, you just add a link with delete class and this is all.

Comment: How is my suggestion (ajax request) any different?

Comment: I am very familiar with jQuery, only that!

Comment: This is more complex. You need to send a request, wait for response, and interpret the response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68526/discussion-between-iamgroot-and-maremp).

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX

```
url = '<?php echo site_url('clientes/delete/'); ?>';
$('.delete').click(function(){
    clientId = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url, 
      data: { clientId: clientId }
    });
})
```

In controller

```
if(isset($_POST['clientId'] {
    $clientId = $_POST['clientId'];
} else {
    $clientId = 'No data';
}
```